# How to rewrite URLs when parent changes to child, and the child is also being rewritten?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site where they want to rewrite some URLs for SEO.  But I'm going in circles trying to figure out how to change parent URL to a child URL, when that Child URL is also being rewritten.

For example:

**OLD:** `/instruments` (parent)
**NEW:** `/mandolins` (child)

The "mandolins" child URL needs to be changed to "acoustic-mandolins"

**OLD:** `/instruments/mandolins`
**NEW:** `/mandolins/acoustic-mandolins`

And then there are children of the "mandolin" child URL that need to be rewritten:

**OLD:** `/instruments/mandolins/f-style-series`
**NEW:** `/mandolins/acoustic-mandolins/f-style-series`

**OLD:** `/instruments/mandolins/a-style-series`
**NEW:** `/mandolins/acoustic-mandolins/a-style-series`

How can I achive this without ending up in a redirect loop?

This is on an apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these `.htaccess` rules to redirect to new urls :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/instruments$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mandolins [R=301,L,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/instruments/mandolins(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mandolins/acoustic-mandolins%1 [R=301,L,QSD]

</IfModule>
```